# How to produce pencil-like images by pure image processing methods?

Tags: filters, computer-vision, computer-graphics

Is it possible to reproduce the following pencil-like image by pure image processing?

[image: Original Image]
[image: Pencil image]

**Notes**:

- The original image: Fig 10 in paper http://www.cs.columbia.edu/cg/aircode/aircode-uist-2017-li-et-al.pdf
- The pencil image: https://youtu.be/AeO4ydc8yqY?t=1m16s

Comment: Canny edge detector?

Comment: I am far from an expert, but I'd have a look into canny edge detector combined with hough transform.